# Docker container files overwritten by host volume share

Tags: node.js, docker, browserify, docker-compose

I am building an application in python which has javascript files. I want to use [browserify](http://browserify.org/), so I want to install some node modules which I can use in my js files with `require` calls. I want these node modules only in my container and not host machine. Here is my Docker setup of node specific container.

```
### Dockerfile
FROM node:5.9.1
RUN npm install -g browserify
RUN mkdir /js_scripts
ADD package.json /js_scripts/                                                                                                           
WORKDIR /js_scripts
RUN npm install # This installs required packages from package.json
RUN ls # lists the node_modules directory indicating successful install.
```

Now I want to share `js files` from my host machine with this container, so that I can run `browserify main.js -o bundle.js` command in the container. Here is my `docker-compose.yml`, which copies `host_js_files` to my `js_scripts` directory.

```
node:
  build: .                                                                                                                              
  volumes:
    - ./host_js_files:/js_scripts
```

Now when I run a container `docker-compose run node bash` and `ls` in the `js_scripts` directory I only see my js files from the host volume, and my `node_modules` directory is not visible. This makes sense, based on how volumes are set up in docker.

However I want to have these `node_modules` in the container to successfully run `browserify` (which looks for these node modules). Is there a good way to do this without globally installing the node modules in the container or having to install the modules in the host machine?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: I'm having precisely same issue. Did you by chance find a working solution?

Comment: Based on the answer marked correct  that says, `You can mount as a volume the node_modules directory to avoid to download all dependencies all the time you create a new container`, I had to have my `node_modules` directory shared from the host machine. This way the first time the container started, it downloaded the node modules in the shared volume, and was accessible every other time the container started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containers should be stateless. If you destroy the container, all data inside it will be destroyed. You can mount as a volume the node_modules directory to avoid to download all dependencies all the time you create a new container.
See this example that installs `browserify` once:

```
### docker-compose.yml
node:
  image: node:5.9.1
  working_dir: /js_scripts
  command: npm install browserify
  volumes:
    - $PWD/host_js_files:/js_scripts
```

First, you should run `docker-compose up` and wait until all packages will be installed. After that, you should run the browserify command as:

```
docker-compose run node /js_scripts/node_modules/.bin/browserify /js_scripts/main.js -o /js_scripts/bundle.js
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to mix your host files with docker container files by folder sharing. After container removing docker deletes all containers data. Docker should know which files belong to containers and which to host(Docker removes all inside container except for volumes). You have two variants to mix host and container files together:

1. Put container files to volume after container was started. (Bad idea, container files will not be removed after removing of container)
2. You can place your host scripts to subfolder in `/js_scripts` or declare all your scripts separately:

   -v ./host_js_files/script1.js:/js_script/script1.js
   -v ./host_js_files/script2.js:/js_script/script2.js